# Connection closed by foreign host postfix error

Tags: networking, server, email, postfix

I'm trying to set up Postfix on the latest Ubuntu and I have followed the official documentation. However, I get the following error message below when trying e.g. `telnet localhost 25`:

"Connection closed by foreign host".

I have searched around, but i'm unable to find any solution. What can cause this error message?

Comment: Plese, give as output from `netstat -atnp` command. Then run `tail -f /var/log/maillog` command and try again `talnat localhost 25`. You will get some output. Give us that output.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Either port 25 is closed or no service is running on that. But probably a good idea would be to [edit] your question to show the steps you did. Moreover the final question should not relate to what the error is but how to solve it, so the answer can be more useful, IMHO.

Comment: @2707974 For both 25 and 143 it says: Local adress 0.0.0.0:25, foreign address: 0.0.0.0:*, state: listen. Regarding "tail -f /var/log/maillog" this file apparantly don't exists.

Comment: Sorry, typo, command is `tail -f /var/log/mail.log`

Answer (score 0):

first you need to see ubuntu system log with this command

**sudo gedit /var/log/syslog**

and if you will see this error "execv( /usr/sbin/tcpd ) failed: No such file or directory" then run this command

**sudo apt-get install tcpd**

it will solve your problem (if not then you need to search your system error on google)